# How can I realize full subtractor using 1X4 DEMUX and logic gates?

Tags: digital-logic, circuit-design, multiplexer

I know how to make it from 1X8 btw.
Also , realize full adder using 1X4 DEMUX and logic gates

Comment: What does *using/from 1×2ᵏ DEMUX* mean? Please present `how to make it from 1X8`.

Comment: https://youtu.be/-9s3xBlcBVM @greybeard

Comment: Don't give me a minutes long video without indicating, preferably in the URL, which part (seconds from start) you refer to. You wouldn't name a book and neither indicate subchapter nor page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You look like having problem in constructing the full subtractor using the 4:1 demux.
As there is 8 outuputs from 0-7 in the full-sub but we only have 4:1 demux which gives us only 4 outputs then we encounter problem less number of ouptut if you go through the min terms condition. That's why it is called digital logic .
First of all convert the 1x4 demux to 1x8 like this :

[here is an answer .](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPdwG.png)

[image]

Now take the mean terms of sum and difference which is :

DIFF={1,2,4,7}

Bo={1,2,3,7}

select them and join in OR gate to get DIFF and Borrow Out.
Hope,It will help you thank you!

Comment: ranjit ale - Hi, Please note the [site rule](/help/referencing) which says that when a post includes content (e.g. text, image, photo etc.) copied from elsewhere, that copied content must be correctly referenced. The source webpage or PDF etc. should be linked as a minimum (references for books / articles should include title, author(s), publisher, edition, page numbers etc.). Therefore please [edit] your answer to include the original source link for that image. Thanks. (As you are new here, please see the [tour] & [help] for the main site rules & etiquette.)

Comment: You should read the site rule about [referencing](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) one more time.

Comment: ranjit ale - Hi, Thanks for trying but, as commented above, your edit is not correct. The image in your answer was copied from elsewhere (i.e. you did not make it yourself). That currently makes your post *plagiarized* as you are using content from elsewhere, without properly referencing the *original source* of that image. For example [here is an answer](/a/559613) which correctly adds a link back to the source webpages, for each of the two images it copied from elsewhere. || Please add the correct link to the source webpage, similar to that example, for the image you copied into your answer.